# Newly installed sytem not able to extract the tar file

Tags: tar

I have installed ubuntu in system. mounted the drive but while extracting the tar file I am getting an error.

`/Downloads$ sudo tar tvzf elasticsearch-7.5.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz /media/asd/LinuxABC/
tar: /media/asd/LinuxABC: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
enter code here`

I Tried this command

```
asd@asd-Inspiron-5559:~/elasticsearch$ sudo tar -C /home/asd/elasticsearch -vzf elasticsearch-7.5.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz 
tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

with the above command it is extracting the file but not able to see the extracted result files.

```
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2019-12-17 04:31 elasticsearch-7.5.1/modules/analysis-common/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0          193639 2019-12-17 04:31 elasticsearch-7.5.1/modules/analysis-common/analysis-common-7.5.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 0/0            1481 2019-12-17 04:31 elasticsearch-7.5.1/modules/analysis-common/plugin-descriptor.properties
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2019-12-17 04:31 elasticsearch-7.5.1/logs/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2019-12-17 04:31 elasticsearch-7.5.1/plugins/
asd@asd-Inspiron-5559:~/Downloads$ cd /home/asd/elasticsearch
asd@asd-Inspiron-5559:~/elasticsearch$ ls
asd@asd-Inspiron-5559:~/elasticsearch$ ls -ltr
total 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to extract the contents of the tar ball into directory `/media/asd/LinuxABC/`?
If that's the case you should use tar like this:

```
/Downloads$ sudo tar -C /media/asd/LinuxABC/ -xvzf elasticsearch-7.5.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

In above command, `-C` tells tar to change to a directory. Then `-xvzf` tells tar to extract the specified file.

The command you used tells `tar` to look for the file `/media/asd/LinuxABC` **inside** the tar ball and extract it.

Also the `t` switch lists the content of the tar ball without extracting. If you are trying to extract the tar ball instead of listing its contents, you shouldn't use this switch.
You should be using the `x` switch as opposed to `t`.

Comment: I can see It is extracting but not  not able to see the extracted file.

Comment: edited the questionns

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you should remove `t` from your `tvzf`. if you look closely, it's `-vzf` in my command.

Comment: After removing t I am getting an error <pre>tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

</pre>

Comment: did you use `vzf` instead `-vzf`? You cannot omit `-` as you've already used `-C` I think.

Comment: yes I used -vzf

Comment: Actually. It should be `-xvzf`.

Comment: yes 'x' worked thanks